# How can an nodelist created by getElementsByClassname or getElementsByTagName display its values as string

Tags: getelementsbytagname, getelementsbyclassname, nodelist, htmlcollection

What I know about getElementsByClassName / getElementsByTagName is that both create a nodelist of the elements in question and that the nodelist elements are treated as objects I have a problem where I want to display the innerHTML of the elements inside of the nodelist but because they are objects this seems to be impossible.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="stylesheet.css">
    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <p id="pp"></p>
        <button onclick="test()">push to test</button>
        <p>dog</p>
        <p>cat</p>
        <p>snake</p>
    </body>
```

//javascript.js file

```
function test() {
    var paragraph = document.getElementsByTagName("p"),
        para1 = paragraph[0].innerHTML,
        ansBox = document.getElementById("pp");
    ansBox.innerHTML = para1;
}
```

This is condensed version of a longer code. I think that the para1 variable should be a string and then the assignment statement should assign that string to the ansBox.innerHTML but instead I get nothing. I have reworked several versions of this code none work. How can you get the text elements inside of a nodelist to display in the ansBox?

Comment: I forgot to add the HTML opening and closing tags in the example above, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is loaded but your DOM hasn't loaded yet if you load your script inside `head` like that

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
    <body>
        <p id="pp"></p>
        <button onclick="test()">push to test</button>
        <p>dog</p>
        <p>cat</p>
        <p>snake</p>
        <script src="javascript.js"></script> <!-- load it here -->
    </body>
```

Also `paragraph[0]` and `ansBox` refer to the same DOM `HTMLParagraphElement` just so you know which does not have anything inside (It is empty to begin with)

Comment: I know that to put the script in the head may cause a delay in the loading process of the document, but it will still load the script itself won't run until the click event of the button so that should be fine. Also paragraph[0] and ansBox are referencing different p tags. Paragraph[0] is part of the getElementByTagId method so it is a nodelist object, and ansBox is assigned with the getElementById which is the only paragraph that is not included with the other tags as it is the only one assigned an ID. Yes the ansBox was assigned empty but then reassigned right afterwords

Comment: @JaMe **paragraph** is the `HTMLCollection`, **paragraph[0]** is the **first** `p` tag in your document which is ***the same element referred to by `ansBox`***, so your code is self-assignment, think you are still confused about the API, included a link for your research [Element.getElementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName)

Comment: Thank you Dummy, (Just reading your username). The problem was that I thought by assigning an ID to the first paragraph I was effectively removing that paragraph from being collected with the 'normal' p tags, but it still is indexed as 0. Also I apparently don't know the difference between nodelist and an HTMLCollection. I have a long way to go!

Answer (score 0):

In the JavaScript code above, you took the HTML inside an empty element and then assign it to itself, and of course you get an empty value.

Comment: I took an empty HTML element and assigned it a nodelist element para1 was assigned a nodelist element from the paragraph variable. Which was assigned an HTML collection because of the getElementsByTag method. Its different things

Comment: Maybe you are mistaken, the `paragraph` variable returns an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName). The variable `para1` is not an `HTMLCollection`. In the above code, `paragraph[0]` returns an [HTMLParagraphElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLParagraphElement), corresponding to the element at position 0 in the `HTMLCollection`, namely the element p whose id is "pp" in the above code.

Comment: Thanks, Tien Coffee. You are right. I thought the ID tag would cause the getElementByTag method to skip over that tag. Nope! It still counted and allowed me to assign an empty tag to itself:) Thanks for taking the time to help